# Declaring variables in Yasm

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, yasm

Here's is a simple program:

```
%include 'utils/system.inc'

section .data
  first:  db 'First is bigger', 0xA,0
  second: db 'Second is bigger', 0xA,0
  a:      db 18
  b:      db 20
section .text
global start
start:
 mov rax, [a wrt rip]
 mov rbx, [b wrt rip]
 cmp rax, rbx
 jle else                        
 mov rsi, qword first
 mov rdx, 0x10
 jmp end
else:
 mov rsi, qword second
 mov rdx, 0x11
end:
 xor rax, rax
 xor rbx, rbx
 mov rax, 0x2000004
 mov rdi, stdout
 syscall

 xor rdi, rdi
 mov rax, 0x2000001
 syscall
```

The problem is that variable `a` contains a different value than 18.
Here's what `lldb` shows me:

> (lldb) p a 
>    (void *) $0 = 0x0000000000001412 
>   (lldb) p b 
>   (void *) $1 = 0x0000000000000014 
>   (lldb) p --format decimal a

Any ideas what's going on? I know that if I declare `a` as `dq`, it will be alright, but I want to understand why it's happening.

Comment: Because you when you do `mov rax, [a wrt rip]` it moves the 8 bytes starting at label `a` and moves that into RAX. You have defined `a` and `b` as bytes and not 8 byte quadwords. You are effectively reading more bytes than needed. For instance 18=0x12 and 20=0x14. When read little endian you'd get 0x1412 in the lower 16 bits of the register which is what you got here.

Comment: If you want to read a single byte you can do `mov al, [a wrt rip]` and `mov bl, [b wrt rip]` and then compare al and bl. If you want to read a byte and have it sign extended through an entire 64-bit register you can do `movsx rax, byte [a wrt rip]` and `movsx rbx, byte [b wrt rip]` and then do the comparison on the 64-bit registers as you did before.

Comment: Oh, that does make sense to me now. Thank you!